# Sending an SMS in an Android application

Tags: android

I made a send application. How can I check message sending without an actual device?

```
sendSms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),template+"and"+phoneNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (phoneNumber.length()>0 && template.length()>0)
        {
            sendSMS(phoneNumber, template);
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please select name & template",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String template)
    {
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Test2Activity.class), 0);
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, template, pi, null);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open two emulators.
2. Run your program in one emulator.
3. In the line "sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, template, pi, null);" substitute phoneNumber with the emulator number. For example, 5554/5556, etc.
4. On successful running of your code the other emulator will receive an SMS.

Comment: welcome. if this solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Click on the tick mark on the left side. hover your mouse and it will appear.

Comment: Hello every one , this code is only works in mobile device only for those numbers without country code, but if i try the number with country code then its not working, and what for international message, i mean how can i send the international message ?